# list[i] in "for" statement does not return the right values

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a `for` statement with the looping variable `i`, which naturally increases by 1 each time. However, when I run the `for` statement with a line that gets index `i` of a certain list, it does something weird. What happens is, it returns very few of the right values and others seemingly randomly.

```
def allchords(thescale,issev):
    for i in range(len(thescale)):
        makechord((thescale[i]),thescale,issev)
```

When `i=0`, it returns `thescale[0]` correctly.

When `i=1`, it returns `thescale[1]` correctly.

When `i=2`, it returns `thescale[3]` for some reason.

When `i=3`, it returns `thescale[6]`

When `i=4`, it returns `thescale[3]`

When `i=5`, it returns `thescale[1]`

When `i=6`, it returns `thescale[0]`

What the heck is going on?

Okay, here is the entire `makechord` function:

```
def makechord(tnc,thescale,issev):
    crdscl=thescale
    for i in range(len(thescale)):
        if crdscl[0] == tnc:
            break
        else:
            tomove=crdscl[0]
            crdscl.pop(0)
            crdscl.append(tomove)

if issev == "y" or "Y":
    thecrd=[(crdscl[0]),(crdscl[2]),(crdscl[4]),(crdscl[6])]
else:
    thecrd=[(crdscl[0]),(crdscl[2]),(crdscl[4])]
print thecrd
```

Comment: This could only happen if `makechord` was *altering `thescale`*.

Comment: I also noticed that `crdsc` is not passed in as a parameter in `allchords()`.

Comment: In other words, `thescale[i]`  is still `thescale[2]` for `i = 2`, but the *value at that position changed*.

Comment: @ericmjl: that doesn't matter; it is read just the once to create the `range()` object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, I realized that after the fact - but would it be good programming practice to pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: Take into account that you pass in `thescale` to the `makechord()` function; that's *not a copy*. Any changes the function makes to that list object are shared.

Comment: Without seeing `makechord()` all we can do however is speculate; please post more code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MpegEVIL you also have a bug, `if issev == "y" or "Y":` is just always true. You must check  `if issev == "y" or issev == "Y":`.

Comment: @Arpegius Why is this? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed modifying `thescale` within `makechord()`:

```
crdscl=thescale
```

just assigns the name `crdscl` to `thescale`, so when you later call

```
crdscl.pop(0)
crdscl.append(tomove)
```

you are actually modifying the contents of `thescale`. An easy way avoid this is by assigning a copy of the contents `thescale` to `crdscl`:

```
crdscl = thescale[:]
```